# How do I solve this issue? (Xcode 12.4)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I finished my iPhone App and tried to submit to the App Store, but it won't get accepted because when you launch it on the iPad at the Landscape orientation, the app glitches and the UI gets messy. It does however work fine when I launch it at the Portrait orientation.

How do I solve this? Is there a way to prevent the App to rotate on the iPad? I tried changing Info.plist settings.

Here's what happens when launching at Landscape mode:

[image]

Comment: you say its a iPhone app, do you even want it to be launched on iPad? If it is not a universal app, it opens in iPad with 2X mark on corner in an ugly zoomed manner, If it is an iPhone app and if you dont want it to open on iPad, go to your target and check only iPhone as deployment target. If you want to stop orientation in both iPhone and iPad you can always uncheck land scape left and right boxes in device orientation.

Comment: It's already checked for iPhone only, but when trying to submit for review, they said:  "We noticed an issue in your app that contributes to a lower quality user experience than Apple users expect:

- Your app was not optimized to support the device screen size or resolution. 

Although your app may be made for iPhone, iPhone apps must run as expected and properly display on iPad"

I also unchecked the landscape left and right boxes.

Comment: Not sure if this is some new rule from apple reviewer but I never faced such issue when it was clearly an  iPhone app :|

Comment: You should optimise the app for landscape mode but If you don't want to give support for landscape mode then just disable it.

Comment: @Arghadip how do I disable it? I tried unchecking the boxes and it didn't work.

Comment: @FelipeDias Restart XCODE and iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

To turn off Landscape support ...

1. Go to the project's build, deployment, resource etc settings by clicking on the project's root in Xcode's Project Navigator window.
2. Under the `Project` section, select the iOS target instance of the app.
3. Select the `General` tab (if it's not already on that)
4. Under the `General` tab's `Deployment Info` section, adjust the supported `Device Orientations` as needed, i.e. uncheck the Landscape options.

Comment: The problem is that those boxes are already unchecked, I don't know what to do.

Comment: I think it's a bug with Xcode not propogating the setting from the iOS target's `General` tab into the iOS `Info.plist` file. Or at least it was for me when I managed to recreate exactly the same problem just now :-)

When I looked at the iOS> Info.plist file I noticed it had multiple entries under the 'Supported interface orientations (iPad) key. Manually deleting the extraneouse entries fixed the issue.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah @shufflingb , It's clearly a bug with Xcode, I also tried deleting those entries, but it just doesn't fix the issue for me. It seems like no one does know how to resolve this, I'm not in a good spot.